# Solving complicated implicit function

Tags: equation-solving

I consider the following function:

```
bound[K10_] := xi - (p0*(Q10 - K10)/(p0 - K10 + Sqrt[(K10)^2 - m1^2]*(1 - 2*alpha)))/(u0Max);
```

This function is basically an implicit function which relates the variable xi to alpha. p0,Q10,m1 and u0Max are constants, which i set to

```
p0 = 1;
m1 = 0.1;
m2 = 0.1;
Q10 =  1/2*(p0 + (m1 - m2)*(m1 + m2)/p0);
Q10Min = (m1^2 + p0^2/4)/p0;
u0Max = p0*(Q10 - Q10Min)/(p0 - Q10Min - Sqrt[Q10Min^2 - m1^2]);
```

K10P is defined in the following way:

```
K10P = -m1^2*Q10*(1 - 2*alpha)^2/(p0^2 - 2*p0*Q10 + Q10^2*(1 - (1 - 2*alpha)^2)) + Sqrt[(-m1^2*Q10*(1 - 2*alpha)^2/(p0^2 - 2*p0*Q10 + Q10^2*(1 - (1 - 2*alpha)^2)))^2 + (m1^4*(1 - 2*alpha)^2 + m1^2*(p0 - Q10)^2)/(p0^2 - 2*p0*Q10 + Q10^2*(1 - (1 - 2*alpha)^2))];
```

The implicit function "bound[K10_]" defines a function of the form xi[alpha], but i would like to solve this implicit function for alpha and obtain an expression depending on xi only, so i try:

```
Solve[bound[K10P] == 0, alpha];
```

Unfortunately, this does not work in the sense that this command runs forever without solving the equation. Do you have any suggestions how to obtain my desired expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could turn it into a polynomial relation using `GroebnerBasis`.

```
bound[K10_] := 
  xi - (p0*(Q10 - K10)/(p0 - K10 + 
         Sqrt[(K10)^2 - m1^2]*(1 - 2*alpha)))/(u0Max);
p0 = 1;
m1 = 1/10;
m2 = 1/10;
Q10 = 1/2*(p0 + (m1 - m2)*(m1 + m2)/p0);
Q10Min = (m1^2 + p0^2/4)/p0;
u0Max = p0*(Q10 - Q10Min)/(p0 - Q10Min - Sqrt[Q10Min^2 - m1^2]);
K10P = -m1^2*
    Q10*(1 - 2*alpha)^2/(p0^2 - 2*p0*Q10 + 
       Q10^2*(1 - (1 - 2*alpha)^2)) + 
   Sqrt[(-m1^2*
        Q10*(1 - 2*alpha)^2/(p0^2 - 2*p0*Q10 + 
           Q10^2*(1 - (1 - 2*alpha)^2)))^2 + (m1^4*(1 - 2*alpha)^2 + 
        m1^2*(p0 - Q10)^2)/(p0^2 - 2*p0*Q10 + 
        Q10^2*(1 - (1 - 2*alpha)^2))];

gb = GroebnerBasis[bound[K10P], {alpha, xi}];
alphaxi = First[gb]

(* Out[43]= -390625 - 37500000 alpha + 37500000 alpha^2 + 1531250 xi + 
 147000000 alpha xi - 147000000 alpha^2 xi - 1875625 xi^2 - 
 217530000 alpha xi^2 + 220410000 alpha^2 xi^2 - 
 5760000 alpha^3 xi^2 + 2880000 alpha^4 xi^2 + 735000 xi^3 + 
 144001200 alpha xi^3 - 149646000 alpha^2 xi^3 + 
 11289600 alpha^3 xi^3 - 5644800 alpha^4 xi^3 - 35985600 alpha xi^4 + 
 38807424 alpha^2 xi^4 - 5698944 alpha^3 xi^4 + 
 2987712 alpha^4 xi^4 - 165888 alpha^5 xi^4 + 55296 alpha^6 xi^4 *)
```

It turns out that this factors into a quadratic and a quartic in `alpha`, so if so desired one can get radical solution branches.

```
Factor[alphaxi]

(* Out[47]= (625 - 1225 xi + 600 xi^2 - 24 alpha xi^2 + 
   24 alpha^2 xi^2) (-625 - 60000 alpha + 60000 alpha^2 + 1225 xi + 
   117600 alpha xi - 117600 alpha^2 xi - 59976 alpha xi^2 + 
   62280 alpha^2 xi^2 - 4608 alpha^3 xi^2 + 2304 alpha^4 xi^2) *)
```

Comment: This works well, thanks for the suggestion. Is it also possible to extend this method such that i can use arbitrary values for p0,m1 and m2?

Comment: You can try that. I think it should work in the same way.

Comment: It works for sure if i replace the values for p0,m1 or m2 by different values, but i am looking for a final expression which depends on p0,m1 and m2 and can be chosen arbitrarily. If i try this, it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's build the function you want to define. We use your equation `bound[K10P] == 0` and more general `Re[bound[K10P]] == 0`

```
Q10 = 1/2*(p0 + (m1 - m2)*(m1 + m2)/p0);
Q10Min = (m1^2 + p0^2/4)/p0;
u0Max = p0*(Q10 - Q10Min)/(p0 - Q10Min - Sqrt[Q10Min^2 - m1^2]);
K10P = -m1^2*
    Q10*(1 - 2*alpha)^2/(p0^2 - 2*p0*Q10 + 
       Q10^2*(1 - (1 - 2*alpha)^2)) + 
   Sqrt[(-m1^2*
        Q10*(1 - 2*alpha)^2/(p0^2 - 2*p0*Q10 + 
           Q10^2*(1 - (1 - 2*alpha)^2)))^2 + (m1^4*(1 - 2*alpha)^2 + 
        m1^2*(p0 - Q10)^2)/(p0^2 - 2*p0*Q10 + 
        Q10^2*(1 - (1 - 2*alpha)^2))];
ContourPlot[bound[K10P] == 0, {alpha, -1, 2}, {xi, 0, 1.2}, 
 FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 150]
ContourPlot[Re[bound[K10P]] == 0, {alpha, -5, 5}, {xi, 0, 1.2}, 
 FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 150]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We see that the `alpha` function has several branches for real values of `xi`. This is the problem. The same can be obtained using

```
bound[K10P] // FullSimplify

Out[]= -((25 (96 - Sqrt[(
        1 - 96 (-1 + alpha) alpha)/((-1 + alpha)^2 alpha^2)] + 1/(
        alpha - alpha^2)))/(12 (196 + 1/(1 - alpha) + 1/alpha - Sqrt[(
        1 - 96 (-1 + alpha) alpha)/((-1 + alpha)^2 alpha^2)] + 
        Sqrt[2] (1 - 
           2 alpha) Sqrt[((1 - 
            2 alpha)^2 (1 + (-1 + alpha) alpha (-48 + Sqrt[(
               1 - 96 (-1 + alpha) alpha)/((-1 + 
                  alpha)^2 alpha^2)])))/((-1 + alpha)^2 alpha^2)]))) +
  xi
```

From here we immediately find (`xif=xi`)

```
xif[alpha_] := (
 25 (96 - Sqrt[(
    1 - 96 (-1 + alpha) alpha)/((-1 + alpha)^2 alpha^2)] + 1/(
    alpha - alpha^2)))/(
 12 (196 + 1/(1 - alpha) + 1/alpha - Sqrt[(
    1 - 96 (-1 + alpha) alpha)/((-1 + alpha)^2 alpha^2)] + 
    Sqrt[2] (1 - 
       2 alpha) Sqrt[((1 - 
        2 alpha)^2 (1 + (-1 + alpha) alpha (-48 + Sqrt[(
           1 - 96 (-1 + alpha) alpha)/((-1 + 
              alpha)^2 alpha^2)])))/((-1 + alpha)^2 alpha^2)]))
```

Get the same curves

```
{Plot[xif[x], {x, 0, 1.2}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
  AxesLabel -> {"alpha", "xi"}], 
 Plot[Re[xif[x]], {x, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
  AxesLabel -> {"alpha", "xi"}]}
```

[image: Figure2]

Define the inverse function

```
\[Alpha] = 
 InverseFunction[
  Function[{alpha}, (
   25 (96 - Sqrt[(
      1 - 96 (-1 + alpha) alpha)/((-1 + alpha)^2 alpha^2)] + 1/(
      alpha - alpha^2)))/(
   12 (196 + 1/(1 - alpha) + 1/alpha - Sqrt[(
      1 - 96 (-1 + alpha) alpha)/((-1 + alpha)^2 alpha^2)] + 
      Sqrt[2] (1 - 
         2 alpha) Sqrt[((1 - 
          2 alpha)^2 (1 + (-1 + alpha) alpha (-48 + Sqrt[(
             1 - 96 (-1 + alpha) alpha)/((-1 + 
                alpha)^2 alpha^2)])))/((-1 + alpha)^2 alpha^2)]))]]
```

If you evaluate the alpha function, then there will be no answer, since the system will not be able to select a branch. But you can choose the branch of the solution of the equation. Suppose we chose branch `0<alpha<1`. Define the function

```
xif[alpha_ /; alpha > 0 && alpha < 1] := (
 25 (96 - Sqrt[(
    1 - 96 (-1 + alpha) alpha)/((-1 + alpha)^2 alpha^2)] + 1/(
    alpha - alpha^2)))/(
 12 (196 + 1/(1 - alpha) + 1/alpha - Sqrt[(
    1 - 96 (-1 + alpha) alpha)/((-1 + alpha)^2 alpha^2)] + 
    Sqrt[2] (1 - 
       2 alpha) Sqrt[((1 - 
        2 alpha)^2 (1 + (-1 + alpha) alpha (-48 + Sqrt[(
           1 - 96 (-1 + alpha) alpha)/((-1 + 
              alpha)^2 alpha^2)])))/((-1 + alpha)^2 alpha^2)]))
```

Make sure that we select the desired branch:

```
{Plot[xif[x], {x, 0, 1.2}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
  AxesLabel -> {"alpha", "xi"}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Re[xif[x]], {x, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
  AxesLabel -> {"alpha", "xi"}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

Define and plot the inverse function

```
alph = InverseFunction[xif]

Plot[alph[x], {x, .3, 0.99}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"xi", "alpha"}]
```

[image: Figure 4]

Comment: How can i choose the branch in particular? Lets suppose that alpha is between 0 and 1 as you already plotted above.

Comment: @RealDestructor See update to my answer .

Comment: This works perfectly fine, thanks for that. Is it also possible to obtain an explicit analytical expression for the inverse function?